# Gas starter in a wood burning fireplace

Tags: hvac

We have a wood burning fireplace with a gas starter that is located with a valve outside of the fire box. My husband leaves the gas running the entire time the wood is on the fire , is this safe ? Should we turn the gas off once the logs catch on fire ?

Comment: Leavng the gas on once the wood has started doesn't immediately come to my mind as a dangerous practice or one that would damage the piping or overheat the fireplace, but wait for comment by experts. It's wasteful of gas. It has been 35 years or more  since we used wood and I do not remember at what point we would turn off the gas. Decades ago I installed ceramic logs, and nowadays hardly  even use the fireplace at all.

Comment: A *possible* benefit of leaving the gas on once the wood has started is that this might lead to more complete combustion of the oils in the wood and so might keep the chimney cleaner.

Comment: Good firewood does not need help to burn.  So a waste of money to leave the gas on.  A gas fire starter also probably not made to be on all the time, like a gas heater would be.